# mvc app; send email using gmail does NOT produce SmtpFailedRecipientException or SmtpFailedRecipientsException

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, gmail, asp.net-identity-2, smtpclient

I have an mvc application that uses gmail to send out an email.

My code:

Successfully sends out an email, providing:

1. I use proper account authentication (username, pw)
2. I send the email to a valid existing email account

I get an exception if I do not use my valid gmail username, pw. (which is good).

**My question and my problem is:**
When my code sends an email to an invalid email account, I do not get an exception of any kind! No SmtpFailedRecipientException, no SmtpFailedRecipientsException; nada.

Why is this happening?  What do I need to change so that I get an exception back when an email is sent to an invalid, non-existent account?

Code in my MVC app:

In Identity.cs

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Web.Helpers.WebMail.Send(message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body, "DoNotReply@ourcompany.com");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;  //Add msg here; set break point when testing; whatever
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

And in AuthConfig.cs, I have the gmail account settings, which we know work.

```
        System.Web.Helpers.WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
        WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
        WebMail.UserName = "OurUserName";
        WebMail.Password = "OurPW";
        WebMail.From = "DoNotReply@OurCompany.com";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
```

In my controller, I have this partial code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, emailSubject, emailBody);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)  
    {
    }
}
```

The controller runs first. I am using the asp.identity2 (UserManager) and SendEmailAsync calls the SendAsync in Identity.cs.

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail doesn't let you know which email addresses it has failed to send emails to to avoid bots looking for valid email addresses. You should get an email later though with details about failed email addresses.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid that was the case with GMail, but couldn't find any documentation explaining that.